# Need to create Json object in php

Tags: php, json

[image]

I want to create a json object using php like below as I need to create a stacked bar chart using `d3.js`, hence I am using data from oracle table and need the json data as above image.
My table has these 3 columns. (ID, NAME, Layers) like:-

```
ID, NAME, Layers
1   ABC   a:8,b:10
2   WWW   c:8,d:7
```

When I am fetching data from oracle, my php code is:-

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))) {
          $streamArr[] = $row;
}    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode($streamArr);
```

I am getting this error:-

> ```
> Warning: [json] (php_json_encode) type is unsupported, encoded as null in line 48
> json output as:-
> [["1","ABC",{"descriptor":null}],["2","WWW",{"descriptor":null}]]
> ```

```
can you please help me in rectifying with this issue?
```

Comment: Could you please provide this data not as a picture.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Instead copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to a field you didn't mention in the example. Maybe just don't select unneeded fields?

If you fix that, you still won't get the desired JSON structure. To get `layers` as an object in every element of `data` in the resulting JSON, you need to convert the string values stored in the database to PHP arrays before encoding.

You could do that with similar code:

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))) 
{
  $row['layers'] = array_map(function($el) {
    return explode(':', $el);
  }, explode(',', $row['layers']));

  $streamArr[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

@marekful answer is really nice, not easiest to understand but efficient and short!

Here you have a longer and not so efficient, but maybe easier to get.

```
$streamArr = array();
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))) 
{
    // Get ID and NAME
    $data = array(
        'id' => $row['ID'],
        'name' => $row['NAME'],
        'layers' => array()
    );
    // Get Layers by split by comma
    $layers = explode(',', $row['layers']);
    foreach ($layers as $layer) {
        // Get layer parts by slit with double-point
        $layersPart = explode(':', $layer);
        foreach ($layersPart as $key => $value) {
            $data['layers'][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    // Add to global array
    $streamArr[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($streamArr);
```

Comment: Thanks Camille, your solution is indeed more readable but quite a bit longer. You will want to be short when you work a lot with code, plus it becomes easier to read, too. `explode` does its own "foreach" internally though, but it uses a tokeniser on the string and iterates over the tokens to create an array. These kind of PHP functions are handy to hide complexity.